# How to setResult from within a PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferencefragment

I created a "Settings" activity using the Android Studio wizard. In this activity is the following PreferenceFragment class..

```
public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
...
}
```

I have some listeners within this PreferenceFragment class and I want to setResult() from within PreferenceFragment class. But I am getting a crash "method not found exception".

How do I access activity/setResult?

Comment: Post your logcat. Which method isn't found?

Answer (score 1):

Fragments cannot have "results", you should call that in activity.

You could do it like this wherever you want to set result:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
//activity in fragment is nullable, 
//so null check is suggested to avoid NullPointerException
if (activity != null) {
    activity.setResult(RESULT_OK);
    activity.finish();
}
```